# Is it possible to use Django bash completion in zsh

Tags: django, bash, zsh, oh-my-zsh

[Django bash completion](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/django-admin/#bash-completion) enables tab-completion of django-admin.py and manage.py commands in bash.

There are autocompletion scripts for `zsh` for django but they does not work with custom commands. One of them is in [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/plugins/django/django.plugin.zsh) project.

I am also aware of `bashcompinit` but it does not seem to work with django-admin, producing following error:

```
./manage.py Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 356, in execute
    self.autocomplete()
  File "lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 266, in autocomplete
    cwords = os.environ['COMP_WORDS'].split()[1:]
  File "bin/../lib/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 23, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'COMP_WORDS'
```

Is it possible to have Django bash completion working with zsh? Or is there some other alternative that would allow using of django admin custom commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could patch `django_bash_completion` something like below:

```
--- django_bash_completion.old  2014-12-23 10:41:35.589103686 +0900
+++ django_bash_completion  2014-12-23 10:43:27.224848105 +0900
@@ -33,7 +33,7 @@

 _django_completion()
 {
-    COMPREPLY=( $( COMP_WORDS="${COMP_WORDS[*]}" \
+    COMPREPLY=( $( env COMP_WORDS="${COMP_WORDS[*]}" \
                    COMP_CWORD=$COMP_CWORD \
                    DJANGO_AUTO_COMPLETE=1 $1 ) )
 }
```

On zsh (zsh-5.0.7 here), it works fine with explicitly using `env(1)`. 
Above patch does not hurt bash (I've tested on bash-4.3.30(1)-release).

Comment: It seems that `emulate` with subshell processing confuse zsh. For example: `() { A=(a b c); emulate -L sh; (A="${A[*]}" printenv A) }` prints nothing, and it causes `KeyError: 'COMP_WORDS'` in this particular case. But `() { A=(a b c); emulate -L zsh; (A="${A[*]}" printenv A) }` prints 'a b c'. Because of this behavior on zsh, I use 'env(1)` to propely export `COMP_WORDS` on my answer.

Comment: This zsh bug has been addressed recently, so we don't need this work around for the upcoming new zsh releases (maybe 5.0.8?).